# API Call to create folder with %-Symbol either fails or doesn't decode

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, encoding, java

I'm implementing REST Calls to Sharepoint in Java. I create folders by sending POST Requests to

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Folder/')/folders/add('NewFolder')
```

This creates a new folder `NewFolder` in the parent folder `Folder`

Now I want a percent in the name:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Folder/')/folders/add('NewFolder%')
```

This fails because the percent is not encoded:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 151: ...

    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:73)
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and all the other sources out there know, that a percent is encoded as `%25`. So I alter my call to

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Folder/')/folders/add('NewFolder%25')
```

But this creates a folder named `NewFolder%25`. The `%25` is not decoded but taken literally.

**So how can I create a folder that justs named `NewFolder%`?**

#### Strange thing is: other characters work

The strang thing is, that percent-encoding works for all the other characters (that I tried)

Lets say I want a space in the folder name. A spaces encodes to `%20` and

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Folder/')/folders/add('New%20Folder')
```

perfectly creates a folder named `New Folder`.

Want something more exotic? Try this:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Folder/')/folders/add('Test%20(%C3%A2)')
```

This creates a folder named `Test (â)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rest end point to add folder with %: `POST http://<site>/_api/web/folders/AddUsingPath(decodedurl='Path')`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/supporting-and-in-file-and-folder-with-the-resourcepath-api

SharePoint folder naming restrictions:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa

Comment: That Call works :-) Thanks.